# Extract multiple JSONs from a string in JAVA

Tags: java, json, mapreduce

### I have a string of the below format

```
"ABCD XYZ
JSON1: {
'key1':'val',
'key2':{
'key2key1':'key2val1',
'key2key2':'key2val2'}
},
MNO
PQRS
JSON2{...}"
```

I need to extract Each JSON from such a string. I am not aware of the text before starting JSON. How to extract them

Comment: json is structured data, if your text is not structured as json, how can you convert it?

Comment: Is each JSON part necessarily preceded by 2 words? Or at least is OK to assume that there will be no `{`, `}`, `[` or `]` in the text outside the JSON? If yes, then you can extract the JSON part using regex and then process it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example, the idea is to find the `{` character.

From there we know that we are processing a JSON string and start storing next characters.

Then each time we find a `}` we decrement a counter, and increment it when we find a `{` .

When the counter gets to 0, we know this JSON has ended, we store it and move on to the next JSON string.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FindJson {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        String src = "ABCD XYZ         JSON1: { 'key1':'val', 'key2':{ 'key2key1':'key2val1',   'key2key2':'key2val2'} }"
                + ",  MNO  PQRS   JSON2{...}";

        StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        List<String> jsonStrings = new ArrayList<>();

        int openingCurlyBraces = 0;
        boolean jsonProcessing = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < src.length(); i++) {

            char current = src.charAt(i);

            switch (current) {

            case '{':
                openingCurlyBraces++;
                jsonProcessing = true;
                break;
            case '}':
                openingCurlyBraces--;

                break;
            default:
                break;

            }

            if (jsonProcessing) {
                jsonBuilder.append(current);

                if (openingCurlyBraces == 0) {

                    jsonStrings.add(jsonBuilder.toString());
                    jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    jsonProcessing = false;

                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println(jsonStrings);

    }

}
```

Output of the list :

[{ 'key1':'val', 'key2':{ 'key2key1':'key2val1',   'key2key2':'key2val2'} }, {...}]

Answer (score 0):

JSON uses double-quoted strings. If you cannot change this, you will have to replace single quotes with double quotes.

Finding the beginning of a JSON object is easy: You can use a regexp:

```
Pattern re = Pattern.compile("JSON([0-9]+):");
Matcher matcher = re.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
   // etc...
}
```

Finding the end of the JSON is less easy: you cannot use a regexp because it can contain nested structures. This solution defines a method `extractJson` that finds the end of the object, and replaces single quotes with double quotes. The resulting string can be fed to your favorite JSON parser:

```
    Matcher matcher = re.matcher(input);
    int index = 0;
    while (matcher.find(index)) {
        int start = matcher.end();
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        index = extractJson(input, start, buf);
        String json = buf.toString();
        // do something with json
    }

...

private static int extractJson(String input, int index, StringBuilder buf) {
    int bracketLevel = 0;
    int st = 0;
    while (index < input.length()) {
        char c = input.charAt(index++);
        switch (st) {
            case 0:
                switch (c) {
                    case '{':
                        buf.append(c);
                        ++bracketLevel;
                        break;
                    case '}':
                        buf.append(c);
                        --bracketLevel;
                        if (bracketLevel <= 0) {
                            return index;
                        }
                        break;
                    case '\'':
                        buf.append('"');
                        st = 1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        buf.append(c);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                switch (c) {
                    case '\'':
                        buf.append('"');
                        st = 0;
                        break;
                    case '"':
                        buf.append('\\');
                        buf.append(c);
                        break;
                     case '\\':
                        st = 2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        buf.append(c);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                switch (c) {
                    case '\'':
                        buf.append(c);
                        st = 1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        buf.append('\\');
                        buf.append(c);
                        st = 1;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static List<LogObject> parse(String str) {
        if (StringUtils.isAllBlank(str)) {
            return Collections.singletonList(new LogObject(StrType.STRING, str));
        }
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '[' || c == ']') {
                list.add(i);
            }
        }
        List<Group> res = Lists.newLinkedList();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
            int j = list.size() - 1;
            Integer lIndex = list.get(i), jIndex;
            char l = str.charAt(list.get(i)), r;
            if (l == '{') {
                while (i < j) {
                    jIndex = list.get(j);
                    r = str.charAt(list.get(j));
                    if (r == '}') {
                        String substring = str.substring(lIndex, jIndex + 1);
                        if (isValidJSON(substring)) {
                            res.add(new Group(lIndex, jIndex));
                            i = j ;
                        }
                    }
                    j--;
                }
            } else if (l == '[') {
                while (i < j) {
                    jIndex = list.get(j);
                    r = str.charAt(list.get(j));
                    if (r == ']') {
                        String substring = str.substring(lIndex, jIndex + 1);
                        if (isValidJSON(substring)) {
                            res.add(new Group(lIndex, jIndex));
                            i = j ;
                        }
                    }
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
        if (res.size() == 0) {
            return Collections.singletonList(new LogObject(StrType.STRING, str));
        }
        List<LogObject> resObjece = Lists.newLinkedList();
        Integer index = 0;
        for (Group re : res) {
            if (re.left > index) {
                resObjece.add(new LogObject(StrType.STRING, str.substring(index, re.left)));
            }
            resObjece.add(new LogObject(StrType.JSON, str.substring(re.left, re.right + 1)));
            index = re.right + 1;
        }
        if (index != size) {
            resObjece.add(new LogObject(StrType.STRING, str.substring(index, size)));
        }
        return resObjece;
    }

    public static boolean isValidJSON(final String json) {
        try {
            final JsonParser parser = new ObjectMapper().getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(json);
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            }
            return true;
        } catch (IOException jpe) {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private static class Group {
        private Integer left;
        private Integer right;

        public Group(Integer left, Integer right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public Integer getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public void setLeft(Integer left) {
            this.left = left;
        }

        public Integer getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public void setRight(Integer right) {
            this.right = right;
        }
    }
```

```
package com.liust.json.model;

public class LogObject {

    private StrType strType;

    private String value;

    public LogObject(StrType strType, String value) {
        this.strType = strType;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public StrType getStrType() {
        return strType;
    }

    public void setStrType(StrType strType) {
        this.strType = strType;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

```
package com.liust.json.model;

public enum StrType {

    STRING,
    JSON,
    INTEGER;
    StrType() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).